# stateless annotation cannot be found

Tags: jpa, java-ee-6

I'm having a little problem using JPA (Hibernate)

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
/**
 * Bean decribing a user.
 * 
 */
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {
...
```

I'm able to use some of the annotation (like @Entity), as shown in the example above.

But @Stateless cannot be found by Eclipse.
Why ?

I'm using the latest version from Hibernate (4.1.9)
I created a user library containing all the required library from the hibernate directory.
I upgraded my dynamic web project with the JPA Project Facet.

Comment: [Stateless](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Stateless.html) is part of EJB, not JPA. You need [a good tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/docinfo.html)

Comment: ok, can you please tell me where to find an EJB implementation ? I thought Hibernate was an implementation for both JPA and EJB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by using TomEE web server, which contains EJB implementation

Answer (score 0):

@Stateless annotation are related to EJB stuffs.For this you need to include EJB3.1 jar in your project build path.